# How to run rails_best_practices gem on a single file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to run rails_best_practices gem on my test file, According to documentation it says to make use of `rails_best_practices -o PATTERN` so i tried

`rails_best_practices -o /test/`

But it is not working , anyone have idea **how to run rails_best_practices gem on a single file** with example. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use  rails_best_practices --with-sublime file_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rails_best_practices --test -o /test/`

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Yes, @TobySpeight - I will expand on it as soon as the OP confirms that it worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete list of rails best practices commands

```
Usage: rails_best_practices [options]
    -d, --debug                      Debug mode
    -f, --format FORMAT              output format
        --without-color              only output plain text without color
        --with-textmate              open file by textmate in html format
        --with-sublime               open file by sublime in html format (requires https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler)
        --with-mvim                  open file by mvim in html format
        --with-github GITHUB_NAME    open file on github in html format. GITHUB_NAME is like railsbp/rails-bestpractices OR full URL to GitHub:FI repo
        --with-hg                    display hg commit and username, only support html format
        --with-git                   display git commit and username, only support html format
        --template TEMPLATE          customize erb template
        --output-file OUTPUT_FILE    output html file for the analyzing result
        --silent                     silent mode
        --vendor                     include vendor files
        --spec                       include spec files
        --test                       include test files
        --features                   include features files
    -x, --exclude PATTERNS           Don't analyze files matching a pattern
                                     (comma-separated regexp list)
    -o, --only PATTERNS              analyze files only matching a pattern
                                     (comma-separated regexp list)
    -g, --generate                   Generate configuration yaml
    -v, --version                    Show this version
    -h, --help                       Show this message
```

Comment: I already tried to follow this but did not find how to run 1 file by using above commands

Comment: rails_best_practices -o "test/" will give you the errors in test file